# UKVI checklist not signed

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals

I've applied for an EEA Family permit for my 2 minor kids, but I went for biometrics and documents scanning,by accident forgot to sign the checklist document. Will this affect our application negatively? Can they refuse us the permit based on this? I'm freaking out a little because we need to be in the UK by the 31st December.

Comment: Email the UKVI at ukvigeneral@mailgb.custhelp.com and ask, quoting your case reference number

Answer (score 2):

no you didn’t forget to sign! They don’t want the checklist, i apply last month for same visa category and i ask the person who was scanning my documents and she said no need for signature and she didn’t even take the checklist and she said it’s personal document just to make you remember what you have to provide! I was worry but that was her answer in my appointment. The real problem is that they take very long time for the outcome! 46 days without answers!!